# error in libffi when building project in Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, kivy

I tried to convert my python and kivy file into an app using the kivy-ios toolchain.

When I go to build the project in Xcode I get this error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64.

```
Ld /Users/noelkehoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nisl-apxldikokudtcbgsurbouyqmhyyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nisl.app/nisl normal (in target 'nisl' from project 'nisl')`
`cd /Users/noelkehoe/kivy-ios/nisl-ios`
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.4.sdk -L/Users/noelkehoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nisl-apxldikokudtcbgsurbouyqmhyyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/noelkehoe/kivy-ios/dist/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.4.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/noelkehoe/kivy-ios/nisl-ios/../dist/lib -F/Users/noelkehoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nisl-apxldikokudtcbgsurbouyqmhyyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/noelkehoe/kivy-ios/dist/frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/noelkehoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nisl-apxldikokudtcbgsurbouyqmhyyf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/nisl.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nisl.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/nisl.LinkFileList -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/noelkehoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nisl-apxldikokudtcbgsurbouyqmhyyf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/nisl.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nisl.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/nisl_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -all_load -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/noelkehoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nisl-apxldikokudtcbgsurbouyqmhyyf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/nisl.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nisl.build/nisl.app-Simulated.xcent -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework GameController -framework Accelerate -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreVideo -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreMotion -framework ImageIO -framework CoreMedia -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Photos -framework Metal -framework WebKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -lbz2 -lsdl2_ttf -lssl -lkivy -lsdl2_mixer -lsdl2 -lpyobjus -lsdl2_image -lios -lffi -lfreetype -lcrypto -lpython3 -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/noelkehoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nisl-apxldikokudtcbgsurbouyqmhyyf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/nisl.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nisl.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/nisl_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/noelkehoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nisl-apxldikokudtcbgsurbouyqmhyyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nisl.app/nisl`

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`
`"_ffi_tramp_alloc", referenced from:`
`_ffi_closure_alloc in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`"_ffi_tramp_free", referenced from:`
`_ffi_closure_free in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`"_ffi_tramp_get_addr", referenced from:`
`_ffi_closure_alloc in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`_ffi_data_to_code_pointer in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`"_ffi_tramp_is_supported", referenced from:`
`_ffi_closure_alloc in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`_ffi_data_to_code_pointer in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`_ffi_closure_free in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`_ffi_tramp_is_present in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`_dlmmap in libffi.a(closures.o)`
`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`
`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Fix is found here: [link](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/pull/695)